# Download multiple files from NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to support download of multiple files from my Node js server to the client. With the below logic implemented in my NodeJS server, I can support sending of single file to the client.

```
res.download('group_documents/sample1.pdf','sample1.pdf', function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    // decrement a download credit etc
  }
});
```

How can i rewrite the above server logic to support downloading multiple files using single request from the client (browser or curl request)?

Comment: You are talking about downloading files from a NodeJS server (thus the browser), then start showing Express code (thus the server), and finish off with something about a client (the browser? or is Node the client now?). Please correct your question

Comment: Do you mean you actually expect multiple files to appear in the user's download folder, or are you open to downloading a zip file or something? Multiple standalone files in one request is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted without any clarification on why it deserves a downvote. I'm facing the same query, and find it a valid one. If any rephrasing of the question is desirable, it should be clarified without downvoting.

Answer (score 9):

On web browser you can not download multiple files at a time.
But you can download archived file of all required files.
Using **express-zip** npm package you can do it easily.

https://github.com/thrackle/express-zip

Install express-zip.

```
npm install express-zip
```

Use following code :

```
res.zip(files);
```

files is an array of objects.
Each object should be :

```
{ path : 'path/to/file', name : 'fileName'}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your target clients are web browsers, then you can't, as the http protocol does not allow for multiple downloads for a single request.

If you really need to do this, then you'd need to either write a custom client application, or (more simply) zip the files into some archive before transmitting them.

Comment: The HTTP protocol does not has a specification for maximum concurrent connections per domain, it is something the browser vendors came up with.

Comment: @RoelvanUden I wasn't really referring to that, more that there is no provision for multiple responses to a single request.