# Nodejs server download multiple files

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to download file1.txt and file2.txt from a nodejs server through one button click.

The process is nodejs server will check the size of the content, and split the content to multiple files if it exceeds certain size.

How should I use nodejs to serve multiple files through http request? 
I believe this answer is wrong: [Download multiple files from NodeJS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215102/download-multiple-files-from-nodejs-server)

Since I've seen one button click to download multiple files. There is an Expressjs api to download one file: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

But how do download multiple files?

Comment: Create a archive file with multiple file and then send it to client.

Comment: Just send multiple download requests when they click the button?