# Ho do we get multiple images from a node backend to an angular frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, frontend

Is there a way to get multiple images to the Angular front end from a nodejs backend.

currently i have this code which is not working properly. But it is only returning one image to the console. (I am not sure how to show this in the webpage either) this is also doing a seperate request to get the image. so it think it is bad practice

component

```
this.vehicleService.getAdvertImage(this.image).subscribe( data => {
        console.log(data);


        const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        this.ADImage = imageURL;


          // let reader = new FileReader();
          // reader.onload = (data: any) => {
          //   this.ADImage = data
          // }

      })
```

Angular service file

```
  getAdvertImage(image: any): Observable<any>{
     let params = new HttpParams();
     params = params.append('image', image)
    const reqURL = `${this.vehicleURL}/get-ad-image`;
    const getImage = this.http.get<any>(reqURL, { params: params }  )
     return getImage;
  }
```

NODE api endpoint

```
router.get('/get-ad-image?:image', async (req, res) => {
    const imageURL = req.query.image
    try {
      
        res.download(imageURL)
             
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ error })
    }
})
```

I need to get few images in one request. If there is a way to do that please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: there shouldn't be any reason to return multiple images in one shot, especially if `'/get-ad-image?:image'` endpoint only handles a single image, make your component reusable and just call it multiple times. If you really want it, then send an array, fetch the images into memory or the filesystem, then return an array of endpoints which will resolve to the images, then loop over the array clientside and add <img> dom elements which point to the endpoints

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for the answer. If i do each call for evey image for each post that will increase the load on the server. Thats why I cannot re use the component to get images one by one. Not sure if im worng here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `res.zip()` with **express-zip** library, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215102/download-multiple-files-from-nodejs-server).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer ill look in to this and let you know how it will go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I can help you, but maybe I can give you a hint into the right direction.
I have my images in a headless-cms (directus) and get & display them via REST-Api the following way:

```
loadImage(ImageUrl) {
    if(imageID!=null){
      this._directusService.getImgAsBlob(ImageUrl).subscribe(res=>{
        this.createImageFromBlob(res);
      })
    }
  }

getImgAsBlob(ImageUrl) {
  const httpOptions = {
    responseType:'blob' as 'json'
    };
      
   return this._http.get<Blob>(ImageUrl, httpOptions);
}

createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.imageBlobUrl = reader.result;
    }, false);
    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

and in the html-file there is a binding to imageBlobUrl:

```
<img class="image" [src]="imageBlobUrl">
```

To get a few images you can just call loadImage-method a few times and save your Blobs into an array.

I hope that this is a little help for you, even though it is not the perfect answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank you for your answer. I tried this but it didn’t work. Like I’m not sure how i can make it work. But thank you very much for your help. I definitely diverted me to the correct path.